# EF6 add-migration fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

After writing my program, I wanted to change the structure of the project.

That means I have a common dll with interfaces and the designed models.

A controller dll and a view dll.

As you can see in the screenshot is my ApplicationDbContext in the controller dll.

[Screenshot Solution Explorer Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9zyT.png)

I'm trying to make an add-migration and update-database but it does not seem to work the up and down methods are empty.

[Configuration.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrjO0.png)

[Migration init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVSUS.png)

Why is that? Where everything was in a dll, it worked.

Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This it's Working.

```
-> Create Model Of EntityStateMedel.(if not create)
-> Models/ApplicationDbContext.cs 
    - Create DbsetFor Your Model.
    - ex : public DbSet<EntityState> EntityStateSet { get; set; }
-> Add-Migration -force "Name"
-> Update-Database -verbos
```